# Databinding to property of observable collection always shows 15

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have the following dependency property in my MainWindow class (inherits from WPF's Window)

```
public ObservableCollection<ComputerListItem> ActiveComputers 
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<ComputerListItem>)this.GetValue(ActiveComputersProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(ActiveComputersProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveComputersProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ActiveComputers", typeof(ObservableCollection<ComputerListItem>), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<ComputerListItem>()));
```

Now I'm trying to give a label the value of `ActiveComputers.Count` so in my XAML I have this:

```
<Window x:Class="ComputerManagerV3.MainWindow"        
        <!-- SNIP -->
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        >
    <Grid>
       <!--SNIP -->
        <Label Name="labelActive" Content="{Binding Source=ActiveComputers, Path=Count}" ></Label>
```

Even in the designer the value the label now shows is 15, strange since the list is initially filled with 13 elements. So I added some tests and no matter how much items there are in the observable collection, the label always shows the value 15 :/. There are also no binding errors shown in the output window so I'm clueless as what to do.

My questions:

- Why is the value of the binding expression always 15?
- How can I write a correct binding so that it always shows the number of items in the
  list
- Is it possible to prepend some text without writing a value
  converter myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your binding's source is the literal `string` "ActiveComputers", which has 15 characters in it. Thus, you're displaying the count of characters in the string, and are not connected to the collection at all.

Try this:

```
Content="{Binding ActiveComputers.Count}"
```

Comment: Ahhh I knew how to fix the issue, but I couldn't see where the 15 was coming from. +1 :)

Comment: Good call on where 15 came from, I really couldn't figure that one out, so obvious in the end :/. Your suggestion for the other problems works nicely as well.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting your `Source` property to a String, and `String.Count` is 15.

To correctly bind to the property, use this instead:

```
<Label Name="labelActive" Content="{Binding ActiveComputers.Count, 
     RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" />
```

As for your 3rd question about the text format, you can use [ContentStringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat.aspx) property to format the content of the `Label`

Comment: Thanks for the link to ContentStringFormat, I knew there had to be something like that built in.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one issue here:

1) In the dependency property registration, you are passing the same list instance to the property of all the instances of your class.

```cs
public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveComputersProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ActiveComputers",
         typeof(ObservableCollection<ComputerListItem>),
         typeof(MainWindow),
         new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<ComputerListItem>()))
```

Instead register with a default value of null and set the properties in the class' constructor.

2) The binding path is wrong. The Source should be a path. ElementName is used to start the path from a given name in the XAML. Try using [Rachel's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11247035/38368)...

Use RelativeSource to start path at window instead of DataSource, then use ActiveComputers.Count as the path.

Comment: +1 for seeing the problem with the PropertyMetadata, that could've caused a few very nasty and hard to trace bugs/

Comment: In regard to issue 2, I didn't notice you did DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}".